# How to use join in an HQL update?

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I know how to join tables in an SQL update but how do I do it in HQL?

Long story: I have items which I process in a run. Each run as an ID and I have a many-to-many relation between items and runs (which is in an extra table).

Now I want to set the state of all items used in a certain run. The naive approach looks like this:

```
update Items item
set item.statue = :done
where item.state = :new
  and :run in item.runs
```

The last line doesn't work. Hibernate can't turn the bag with runs into something that can be used in a where clause. What's the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing **item.runs** to **elements(item.runs)**. I'm not sure it will work for an update, though, because joins in HQL updates usually need to be expressed in a subselect. So if it doesn't work, try something like:

```
update Items i1
set i1.statue = :done
where i1.state = :new
and i1 in (
  select i2
  from Items i2
  where :run in elements(i2.runs)
)
```